Make change in the table structure in a replicated environment for Postgresql
I have a table in production whose structure I want to modify. I can ALTER the table to add column but the column gets added at the end, may be the order may not matter. But at least visually I see it as the last column. The table was created at the last release and it was empty. So, I thought of dropping it & re-creating it in my flyway script. But it led to build failure as the database replication is on in production. How to deal with it? Database is PostgreSQL. At this point of time, I do not have information about scheme of replication as the production environment is with client.

Are you using Physical Replication or Logical Replication?

@SahapAsci I will ask the DBA & get back to you

@SahapAsci What if it is logical replication?

@SahapAsci it is a logical replication. If in subscriber we drop replicated table & recreate will it do?

If it is logical replication, you will have to add the new table to the publication and refresh the publication on the subscriber.
